# MSChart: Setting Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum to a floating point number

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

Problem in details is that:

Setting `Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 7.51` (in a separate thread (I have tried to set in the same UI thread as well)) is displayed as 7.00!

During debugging the code; value of AxisX.Minimum is successfully set to to 7.51 but right after entering the "Empty" Chart_PrePaint() event handler it is turned to 7.00 and remains 7!

Any information about this issue?

Comment: I can't confirm this. I set it, it works and in the PrePaint it is still set. Something else is happening somewhere ...! (It's a double btw..)

Comment: Well, I cannot find any other line of code altering the `AxisX.Minimum` anywhere else in the project! Knowing that the `AxisX.Maximum` is set to  30.22 and remains as is with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to detect the cause of the problem:

`ChartValueType.Int64` was the `XValueType` of the axis, changing it to `ChartValueType.Single` solved the problem.

Thanks for help.